# How would I start an inmemory version of cockroachDB to run my BDD?

Tags: cockroachdb

Hello all I am working creating on BDD's with cockroach DB. Unfortunately I am not able to find any reference document in order to create a BDD for cockroach DB.

Answer (score 1):

If by BDD you mean behaviour-driven development, BDD isn't something you "create", it's a style of development that is guided and tested by the behaviours your application is intended to provide. I don't think CockroachDB offers any docs specifically related to developing using BDD, but there is a [doc](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/local-testing.html) for general testing best practices with CockroachDB . Alternatively, a little background reading might be helpful:

[BDD in general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development)

and [applying it to databases](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/devops/database-devops/what-is-behaviour-driven-database-development/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).